# AngularJS: Get attribute value from custom tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am a newbie of AngularJS don't know what i am doing wrong here is my code. Basically i am trying to get attribute value of post-id from my index.html and print it in console from my controller.

In my index.html:

```
<post-creator post-id="5" category="1"></post-creator>
<script src="components/post-creator/post-creator.component.js"></script>
```

post-creator.component.js:

```
function controller($http) {
        var model = this;

        model.$onInit = function () {
            console.log("id again:" + model.postId);
        }
module.component("postCreator", {
        templateUrl: "components/post-creator/post-creator.template.html",
        bindings: {
            value: "<"
        },
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: ["$http", controller]
    });
```

Comment: shouldn't your `bindings` contain `postId` instead of `value`?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Added that as answer..

Comment: Thank you for the example. I didn't notice that.

Comment: np, glad that helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the HTML, you are passing `post-id="..." category="..."`, they should be part of `bindings` of your `component` and not `value`. Like this:

```
bindings: {
    postId: "<",
    category: "<"
}
```

Here's a sample working example:

```js
var module = angular.module("myApp", [])

function controller($http) {
  var model = this;

  model.$onInit = function() {
    console.log("id again:" + model.postId);
  }
}

module.component("postCreator", {
  template: "<div>post creator</div>",
  bindings: {
    postId: "<",
    category: "<"
  },
  controllerAs: "model",
  controller: ["$http", controller]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <post-creator post-id="5" category="1"></post-creator>
</div>
```